# Agents falling from navmesh on the navmesh under it

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

my game is a click to move game.In an area, I've got a navmesh walkable and under it there is another walkable part of navmesh.
My problem is that usually after I attack an enemy, sometime but not always, when I click to move my player falls on the navmesh below. I ve got the same problem on the enemies, who simply are programmed to follow the player and attack while in range, who sometime fall.
Nobody has rigidbodies attached.

Any idea of the problem? Feel free to ask ask more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your navmesh is set to automatically create off mesh links: open Navigation window, click Object tab, select your terrain/ground object, make sure Generate OffMeshLinks is unchecked. If that fixes the problem, and you want auto generated off mesh links, you can try adjusting the Drop Height and Jump Distance under the Navigation->Bake tab. You can also try toggling Auto Traverse Off Mesh Links on the NavMeshAgent component.

Comment: In the end I found the issue. If i disable and enable the agent component, the navmesh agent falls on the navmesh area under the one i was on.